# Can I use vuepress and vuepress-theme-hope to make some things like this?

Tags: markdown, documentation, vuepress

I'm writing a documentation with vuepress.

(How) Can I use markdown, vuepress and vuepress-theme-hope to make some things like this:
[image: discord.py]
(from [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot))

or do I need to write HTML codes?

Answer (score 1):

The following MarkDown produces "***Something like this***"

```md
# API Reference
The following section outlines the API...

## Bots
### Bot
`class ...`

| Attributes                      | Methods                         |
| :------------------------------ | :------------------------------ |
| [link](https://www.google.com/) | [link](https://www.google.com/) |
| [link](https://www.google.com/) | [link](https://www.google.com/) |
| [link](https://www.google.com/) | [link](https://www.google.com/) |
|                                 | [link](https://www.google.com/) |
|                                 | [link](https://www.google.com/) |
```

The above MarkDown is rendered below

---

## API Reference

The following section outlines the API...

### Bots

#### Bot

`class ...`

| Attribute | Methods |
| --- | --- |
| link | link |
| link | link |
| link | link |
|  | link |
|  | link |

---

Instead of two separate columns of links, they are combined into one table.
Again, "***Something like this***"